# How can update the Realm DB when the JSON updates

Tags: android, json, realm

Hi friends i am new to the realm when ever my json updates i need to update my realm database too but i cant see the updated JSON values in the realm i am cant able to understand why it is happening like that please help me out

```
 final JSONArray userarray = response.getJSONArray("user");
                    final Realm invoicerealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    invoicerealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
//                            realm.delete(Upcoming_requests_adapter.class);
                            invoicerealm.createAllFromJson(Upcoming_requests_adapter.class,userarray);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if, you need to update your database, perspective RealmObject should contain a primary key on which update operation will be performed. That means-

> Upcoming_requests_adapter.java should have a primary key.

If it contains a primary key then the following transaction will create a new RealmObject or will update an existing RealmObject depends on primary key.

```
final Realm invoicerealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
invoicerealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(Upcoming_requests_adapter.class, userarray);
    }
});
```